# Handle "excluded" updates in ksqlDB

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I've created a stream and a table in this way:

```
CREATE STREAM user_stream
  (id VARCHAR, name VARCHAR, age INT)
  WITH (kafka_topic='user_topic', value_format='json', partitions=1);


CREATE TABLE user_table AS
  SELECT
    id,
    LATEST_BY_OFFSET(name) as name,
    LATEST_BY_OFFSET(age) as age
  FROM user_stream
  GROUP BY id
  EMIT CHANGES;
```

And submit some event to the `user_topic` as:

```
{ "id": "user_1", "name": "Sherie Shine", "age": 31 }
{ "id": "user_2", "name": "Liv Denman", "age": 52 }
{ "id": "user_3", "name": "Frona Ness", "age": 44 }
```

Then query the table as:

```
SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE age > 40 EMIT CHANGES;
```

We'll get two rows:

```
+------------+----------------+-------+
|SID         |NAME            |AGE    |
+------------+----------------+-------+
|user_2      |Frona Ness      |44     |
|user_3      |Liv Denman      |52     |
```

Post another message to the `user_topic`:

```
{ "id": "user_3", "age": 35 }
```

I'm expecting `user_3` will be removed from the current query, but I've received nothing.

If I interrupt the current query with Ctrl+C and issue the same query again, I'll see only `user_2` as it's the only one with `age > 40` now.

How can we handle the update to remove a row from the filter?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is gone after upgrading confluent-6.1.1 to confluent-6.2.0.